# Ubuntu 17.04 vim colors

Tags: bash, themes, gnome-terminal, vim, colors

I just installed Ubuntu 17.04. After setting up vim I noticed my colors are wrong. Here's what I mean:[image]

You can see that system background is showing through the vim background in places where there is no text.

**What I've tried**
I've made sure that my vimrc has `set t_Co=256` in it. Also as you can see in the above image my bashrc has `force_color_prompt=yes`. I've also added `bg=dark` to my vimrc. For the curious the ouput of `echo $TERM` is `xterm-256color`. I've made sure to source both of those files and tried restarting the terminal.

It seems as if there is a problem with 256 color support in gnome-terminal for Ubuntu 17.04.

**Is this a problem for anyone else? Has anyone solved it?**

Comment: Are you using something else than the default vim color scheme? I've had similar problems with solarized in vim, and not using the solarized theme for the terminal.

Comment: Yes I am. But I've tried multiple themes and they worked in 16.04.

Comment: Please see https://superuser.com/questions/1205861/gnome-terminal-vim-colors-not-updating for this same question and an answer.

Answer (score 0):

While you are in your terminal tab.

Go the the window settings and select the "Edit" menu. In that there is a "Profile Preferences".

Now select the "Colors" and adjust your transperancy or unselect it.

[image]